# Logic for preparing response body should be on @Service or on @Controller?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I'm working with **Spring Boot** and will try to explain a situation where my doubt occurs.

Imagine that `MyObject` has some other objects composing it.

```
public class MyObject {

    private Integer id;
    private MyObject2 obj2;
    private MyObject3 obj3;
    private MyObject4 obj4;

    // getters and setters ...

}
```

Some of this fields, have `MyObject` composing them.

Let's say `MyObject2` have `MyObject` as a field, doing some sort of relation ship between both sides. (eg.: ManyToOne)

```
public class MyObject2 {

    // other fields
    private List<MyObject> objs;

    // getters and setters

}
```

Since I'm working with REST APIs and need this entities to be returned into a Json, infinite recursion can happen when being serialized, since one entity references the other.

As I was solving the recursion problem creating DTO's and helper classes, I had a doubt on *where the logic for calling DTO's and helper classes should go.*

**Helper.java**

```
public static MyObject buildPrettyMyObject(MyObject obj) {
    obj.setObj2(null);

    return obj;
}
```

The logic for preventing infinite recursion is on removing all `MyObject2` references on a `MyObject` reference from `MyObject2` by setting to `null`.

My Helper class do the job, but, where should I call it?

In my Controller:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> handleRequestOfRetrieveAllMyObject2() {
    List<MyObject2> objs2 = obj2Service.findAll();
    objs2.forEach(obj2 -> obj2.getObjs().forEach(obj -> Helper.buildPrettyMyObject(obj)));

    return ResponseEntity.ok(objs2);
}
```

In my Service:

```
public List<MyObject2> findAll() {
    List <MyObject2> objs2 = obj2Repository.findAll();
    objs2.forEach(obj2 -> obj2.getObjs().forEach(obj -> Helper.buildPrettyMyObject(obj)));

    return objs2;
}
```

**It should be a job for the Service layer, or it should be a job for the Controller layer?**

I'm doing this at the Controller layer, since the controller is responsible for return the response to the client and the Service layer should only do business rules and has to be reusable.

Am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm doing this at the Controller layer, since the controller is
>   responsible for return the response to the client and the Service
>   layer should only do business rules and has to be reusable. Am I doing
>   this wrong?

You are doing it right. It is a presentation/serialization concern, so ideal candidate for that is controller layer. But this is one of those [Bikeshedding](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bikeshedding) problem on which you can spend days or even weeks discussing about it. You are doing it right, just move on.